# Unable to change background color of selected row in DataTable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to highlight or change the background color of the selected row in jQuery Datatable. I am using **rowCallback** but nothing is working. Here is my code :

```
//..global variable , this is id of selected row
let selectedRowProfileId = ''; 

//..ready function
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#data-table').length !== 0) 
{
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
        autoFill: true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "columnDefs":
            [
                {
                    "targets": [1],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                },
            ],

    });
}});

//..Click event fired whenever a user click on a cell or row
$('#data-table tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {



const tr = $(this).closest('tr');

const table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
const data = table.row(tr).data();

selectedRowProfileId = data[1];

//..Update UI
UpdateUIBySelectedProfileId(selectedRowProfileId);
});

UpdateUIBySelectedProfileId(selectedRowProfileId){

  //..Here i do ajax call based on the selectedRowProfileId
  //..Upon receiving the respone in success bloc of ajax call
  //..i re-draw the table like this :
  const clients = JSON.parse(reponse);
  const table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
  table.clear().draw(); 

  clients.forEach(client => {
     table.row.add([
        client['LastKnownZone'],
        client['ProfileId'],
        client['macAddress'],
        client['ssId'],
        client['Statut'],,
        client['LastLocatedTimeString'],
     ]);
  });

  if (selectedRowProfileId !== '')
                {
                    table.rows().eq(0).each(function (index)
                    {

                        const row = table.row(index);
                        const data = row.data();
                        //console.log(data[1]);
                        if (data[1] === selectedRowProfileId)
                        {
                            $(row).css("background-color", "Orange");
                            //$(row).addClass('label-warning');
                            //console.log(row);
                        }

                    });
                }


                table.draw();

}
```

So What i want to achieve is to highlight the previously selected row upon redrawing the table.

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the above code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you try to see what row contains by putting breakpoints?

Comment: @Xris : Have you succeeded to integrate my solution into your code?

Comment: Yes i just finished integrating your solution it works mate!!!, i had to learn how to use ajax option integrated in Datatable and every things works. Thanks a lot mate, i really appreciate taking your time. I am gonna mark the solution as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to change row background color from within [`rowCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) which is not supposed to work, since it is triggered before table is rendered.

Instead, you may put 'coloring' code inside row click handler (as suggested [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html))

Following **demo** is to illustrate that concept:

```js
const dataSrc = [
  {item: 'apple', cat: 'fruit'},
  {item: 'pear', cat: 'fruit'},
  {item: 'carrot', cat: 'vegie'}
];

const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: dataSrc,
  columns: ['item', 'cat'].map(item => ({title: item, data: item}))
});

$('#mytable').on('click', 'tr', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  console.log(dataTable.row($(this)).data());
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: gray !important;
}

tbody tr:not(.selected):hover {
  cursor: pointer !important;
  background: lightgray !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code presumes that you're **not** using ['select'](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) extension for DataTable

If above selection is required to be persistent (upon table re-draw, e.g. triggered by AJAX-call), there can be introduced an array that stores id's of table records (e.g. `const selectedRowIds = []` within global scope), and [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option can be employed in order to re-apply class `selected` upon re-draw if row id is found within `selectedRowIds`:

```
const dataTable = $("#mytable").DataTable({
    ...
    createdRow: (row, data, dataIndex, cells) => {
        if (selectedRowIds.indexOf(data.id) > -1)
            $(row).addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

Also, row click handler should be extended with the logic that will append/remove selected row id into/from `selectedRowIds`:

```
$("#mytable").on("click", "td", function () {
    //get clicked table row node
    const clickedRow = dataTable.row($(this).closest("tr"));
    //append/remove selected row 'id' property value to global array
    selectedRowIds = $(clickedRow.node()).hasClass("selected")
         ? selectedRowIds.filter(rowId => rowId != clickedRow.data().id)
         : [...selectedRowIds, clickedRow.data().id];
    //toggle class 'selected' upon clicking the row
    $(clickedRow.node()).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

You may find the complete **demo** over [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rj80rx5vzm?fontsize=14) or inspect that with your browser's Dev Tools, using [this](https://rj80rx5vzm.sse.codesandbox.io/) link.

Comment: deleted my answer and merged our two answers together ;-) I wrote mine as you wrote yours

Comment: Thanks. Slightly re-formatted that (don't like long hyperlinks ;)

Comment: that's fine :-)

Comment: Thank you. The reason why i have use rowCallback is that i re-draw the table in the function "UpdateUIBySelectedProfileId(selectedRowProfileId)", so i want to highlight the previously selected row each redraw of the table.

Comment: @Xris sounds like you wrote the wrong question. you might want to explain better the problem you're facing and include the body of the `UpdateUIBySelectedProfileId ` function. Also, it might be good to add a complete code snippet (working but with the issue you are facing)

Comment: @Xris : would you try the above solution? In my environment selection is persistent even upon switching pages or re-drawing table on search filter. If it doesn't work for you, I'm going to need to see what's going on behind the scenes (within `UpdateUIBySelectedProfileId`) to adjust my answer. Possibly, global variable that stores id's of the selected row and re-selecting rows that are in that array upon table draw would do the trick.

Comment: I just added the code for UpdateUIBySelectedProfileId. What do you mean re-selecting rows ? Once again thanks for the comment

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't use DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to retrieve your data?

Comment: I have never used dataTable ajax option before. But i still don't see how that would help select the previously selected row and change its color. Thanks

Comment: I made modifications to my codes, i removed the rowCallback and added some logic in UpdateUIBySelectedProfileId, but still the background color of selected row is not set to orange . Please any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have updated my answer to fulfill your requirement of persistent selection. Hopefully, it works for you, so you may accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing background color of td tags of row.

```
$('td', row).css('background-color', 'orange');
```