# How to show rows as selected in JQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have s sample user data in json format. I have a set of selected users from this list. I need to show these users as selected in datatable with the row and checkbox selected. How to do this.

I'm able to get the data from datatable with following code

```
var rowData = table.rows({ selected: true }).data().toArray();
```

and I save this user data to my server on a button click. I now didn't find a way to return selected users to datatable and show them as selected. I'm using Angular JS and NodeJS.

Is there a possible way to do this. I didn't find the Datatables documentation useful or informative about "Retaining row selection on refresh" topic.

Here is my initialization code

```
table = $('#datatable1').DataTable({
   responsive: true,
   columnDefs: [
      {
          orderable: false,
          className: 'select-checkbox',
          targets: 0
      },
      {
           targets: 1,
           visible: false,
           searchable: false
      }
  ],
  select: {
     style: 'multi',
     selector: 'td:first-child'
  },
  language: {
     searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
     sSearch: '',
     lengthMenu: '_MENU_ items/page',
  }
});
```

I'm using userId's as a column which is hidden to display.

I'm sending a flag with each user whether he is selected and also a separate list of selected users. Not sure which will be useful for representation. Any possibility with table configurations or workaround in js is also ok.

Comment: Use your list of selected rows and [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to assign class 'selected' to necessary rows and set checkbox checked inside those.

Comment: ...You may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954902/11299053) post for code examples (there's used slightly different method with `createdRow`. Though, it's not essential,as both can work in this case).